# Почему не запускается сборка, как исправить?

Tags: vue.js, gulp, webpack, npm

```
gulp development
C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13
      throw new Error(errors.unsupportedEnvironment());
      ^

Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:166:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)

C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master>npm uninstall node-sass&& npm install node-sass
npm WARN @stylelint/postcss-css-in-js@0.37.2 requires a peer of postcss@>=7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @stylelint/postcss-markdown@0.36.1 requires a peer of postcss@>=7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^6.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-react@^7.20.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^4 || ^3 || ^2.3.0 || ^1.7.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-axios@3.2.0 requires a peer of vue@>= 3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-loader@15.9.3 requires a peer of css-loader@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN rarus@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\gulp-watch\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

audited 2241 packages in 21.165s

109 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

> node-sass@4.14.1 install C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/win32-x64-88_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/win32-x64-88_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@5.0.0 install C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v5.0.0/win32-x64-88_binding.node
Download complete  ] - :
Binary saved to C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-88\binding.node
Caching binary to C:\Users\Anriko\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\5.0.0\win32-x64-88_binding.node

> node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Anriko\\Desktop\\rarus-test-master\\rarus-test-master\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@15.4.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:199:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:199:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:199:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:199:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:199:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Anriko\\Desktop\\rarus-test-master\\rarus-test-master\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflag
s=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v15.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN @stylelint/postcss-css-in-js@0.37.2 requires a peer of postcss@>=7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @stylelint/postcss-markdown@0.36.1 requires a peer of postcss@>=7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^6.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-react@^7.20.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^4 || ^3 || ^2.3.0 || ^1.7.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-axios@3.2.0 requires a peer of vue@>= 3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-loader@15.9.3 requires a peer of css-loader@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN rarus@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\gulp-watch\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Anriko\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-12T12_35_06_218Z-debug.log

C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master>gulp development
node:assert:399
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Anriko\Desktop\rarus-test-master\rarus-test-master\gulpfile.js:111:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at execute (C:\Users\Anriko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js:36:18) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Версия ноды не поддерживает эту версию модуля для sass. Откатитесь на более старую версию - должно помочь